# Formatting problem on Webpage with IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I inherited a webpage to manage at work.  I needed to add a new button so simply edited the existing jpeg to include the button and added a hyperlink to the jpg to open the link.

In Chrome, Firefox etc. all is well but now I get a weird formatting on IE.

I am NOT a web developer and am perplexed.

Thank you in advance for your help and advice.

The website is www.kimberleyjackson.com.

Sincerely,

Jason

Comment: Please specify which version(s) of IE you're having problems with. It makes a big difference.

Comment: @Spudley: It seems to look wrong in IE7/8. I present to you a single line of the source: `<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12">`

Comment: @thirtydot - hehe. that tells me all I need to know. (ironic that it breaks in IE and not Chrome/FF though!)

Answer (score 3):

That page is not really HTML, it's using Word-generated [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) which as you see is ancient and deprecated technique.

The only thing I can suggest is to rewrite the page using "pure" HTML without all this fancy and deprecated stuff.

As you're not a web developer I fear you'll have to hire one - web page should be developed by web developer, not by document processing software.

Answer (score 1):

Like above people have said, this is not going to be an easy page to maintain.  That being said... is your new image the same size as the old image?  If not, that may be causing misalignment.  What changes exactly did you make?